# Converting Unicode codepoints into Unicode character using Python 3.3.1

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-3.x

I've this string :

```
sig=45C482D2486105B02211ED4A0E3163A9F7095E81.4DDB3B3A13C77FE508DCFB7C6CC68957096A406C\u0026type=video%2F3gpp%3B+codecs%3D%22mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22\u0026quality=small\u
0026itag=17\u0026url=http%3A%2F%2Fr6---sn-cx5h-itql.c.youtube.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsource%3Dyoutube%26mt%3D1367776467%26expire%3D1367797699%26itag%3D17%26factor%3D1.25%2
6upn%3DpkX9erXUHx4%26cp%3DU0hVTFdUVV9OU0NONV9PTllHOnhGdTVLUThqUWJW%26key%3Dyt1%26id%3Dab9b0e2f311eaf00%26mv%3Dm%26newshard%3Dyes%26ms%3Dau%26ip%3D49.205.30.138%26sparams%
3Dalgorithm%252Cburst%252Ccp%252Cfactor%252Cid%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Csource%252Cupn%252Cexpire%26burst%3D40%26algorithm%3Dthrottle-factor%26ipbits%3D8%26fexp%3D9
17000%252C919366%252C916626%252C902533%252C932000%252C932004%252C906383%252C904479%252C901208%252C925714%252C929119%252C931202%252C900821%252C900823%252C912518%252C911416
%252C930807%252C919373%252C906836%252C926403%252C900824%252C912711%252C929606%252C910075%26sver%3D3\u0026fallback_host=tc.v19.cache2.c.youtube.com
```

As you can see it contains the both forms:

- **%xx**. For example, `%3`, `%2F` etc.
- **\uxxxx**. For example, `\u0026`

I need to convert them to their unicode character representation. I'm using `Python 3.3.1`, and `urllib.parse.unquote(s)` converts only `%xx` to their unicode character representation. It doesn't, however, convert `\uxxxx` to their unicode character representation. For example, `\u0026` should convert into `&`.

How can I convert both of them?

Comment: I can understand wanting to decode this, but what makes you think you need to "convert to ASCII"?

Comment: I'm parsing the string, and want to split it.

Comment: You can parse a Unicode string, too.

Comment: @doomster: `\u0026` makes it difficult to understand the string. `&` is much better if I convert it first. I'm learning Python, so that is important for me.

Comment: Hmm, having a single Unicode character `'\u20ac'` is IMHO easier to parse than the nine characters '`%e2%82%ac`', each of which can occur in other letters' representation, too.

Comment: @doomster: I want to convert `\u0026` to `&` (which is what it is). then it is easy to read and parse.

Comment: If you have a string that contains these six letters (backslash, u, zero...) and it is not just that printing the `repr()` of the string gives you these, then it might make sense to un-escape this back to Unicode. However, it won't give you ASCII for e.g. `\u20ac` (Euro sign) but a Unicode string, which makes your question about converting to ASCII a bit confusing...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I edited the question. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: @doomster: Please see the question now. I've edited it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

- Choose to interpret it as JSON; that format uses the same escape codes. The input does need to have quotes around it to be seen as a string.
- Encode to latin 1 (to preserve bytes), then decode with the `unicode_escape` codec:

  ```
  >>> urllib.parse.unquote(sig).encode('latin1').decode('unicode_escape')
  '45C482D2486105B02211ED4A0E3163A9F7095E81.4DDB3B3A13C77FE508DCFB7C6CC68957096A406C&type=video/3gpp;+codecs="mp4v.20.3,+mp4a.40.2"&quality=small&itag=17&url=http://r6---sn-cx5h-itql.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&mt=1367776467&expire=1367797699&itag=17&factor=1.25&upn=pkX9erXUHx4&cp=U0hVTFdUVV9OU0NONV9PTllHOnhGdTVLUThqUWJW&key=yt1&id=ab9b0e2f311eaf00&mv=m&newshard=yes&ms=au&ip=49.205.30.138&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&burst=40&algorithm=throttle-factor&ipbits=8&fexp=917000%2C919366%2C916626%2C902533%2C932000%2C932004%2C906383%2C904479%2C901208%2C925714%2C929119%2C931202%2C900821%2C900823%2C912518%2C911416%2C930807%2C919373%2C906836%2C926403%2C900824%2C912711%2C929606%2C910075&sver=3&fallback_host=tc.v19.cache2.c.youtube.com'
  ```

This interprets `\u` escape codes just like it Python would do when reading string literals in Python source code.

Comment: The second option worked. Could you explain how it works? Why did you use `encode('latin1')` and then `decode('unicode_escape')`? What each of them do?

Comment: I would suggest using encode() which uses your native encoding. latin1 really just causes more problems than it solves. If you already have unicode characters, they will be encodable. Going the other way is where you need to care about bytes that don't fit the encoding. And in that respect you should really use 'surrogateescape' error handling if you know you need to handle binary data.

Comment: @Nawaz - in order to unescape the \u sequences, you need to call `decode('unicode_escape')` to decode the unicode escape sequences. But `decode` only works on bytes objects not on unicode strings (which is what you get from `parse.unquote`). He calls encode first to get bytes from the string and then decodes the bytes back to unicode to get text with the unescaped sequences.

Comment: @underrun: Using latin1 is sorta-safe to get from unicode characters that are really data back to bytes. Since this is URL-encoded data, we could decode to unicode_escape first then URL-decode to avoid any potential conflicts with url-encoded characters.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm guessing right, this is more or less a URL. The '%xx' encodes a single byte outside the allowed character set. The '\uxxxx' encodes a Unicode codepoint. I believe that it is normal for URLs to encode Unicode characters as UTF-8 and then to encode the bytes outside the allowed charset as '%xx' (which affects all multibyte UTF-8 sequences). This makes it surprising that there are '%xx'-encoded bytes already, because translating the Unicode codepoints will make the conversions irreversible.

Make sure you have tests and that you can verify the actual results, because this seems like it was unsafe. At least *I* don't fully understand the requirements here.