# Regex compatibility in IE7

Tags: regex, internet-explorer

Trying to make my JavaScript code IE7 compatible and I am running into (possible a bug) some issues with IE7.

```
var elements = url.match(/^:(\d+)(.*)/);
```

Returns null on valid matches:

```
:80/site1/www
:8080/site2/public_html
```

Not sure how else to rewrite this. Any ideas?

Comment: Damn, it's hard testing this when IE7's developer "tools" don't even have a console. Perhaps the `:` needs escaping?

Comment: Tell your boss that full support of IE7 is more work than it's worth.

Comment: No dice escaping it. @Barmar One day..

Comment: I cannot reproduce these results. If I run this http://jsbin.com/ODuNihU in IE7 I get the exact same results as I get in all browsers. Perhaps something else is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the implementation differences:

```
* Internet Explorer ≤ 8 excludes almost all empty values from the resulting array (e.g., when two delimiters appear next to each other in the data, or when a delimiter appears at the start or end of the data). This behavior differs when using a string as the delimiter.

* Internet Explorer ≤ 8 and older versions of Safari do not splice the values of capturing groups into the returned array.

* In Internet Explorer, captured values for nonparticipating capturing groups are incorrectly returned by RegExp.prototype.exec and String.prototype.match as an empty string rather than undefined, making it impossible to determine group participation.

* Internet Explorer ≤ 8 increments lastIndex after zero-length matches when using RegExp.prototype.exec and RegExp.prototype.test.

* In Internet Explorer, captured values for nonparticipating capturing groups are incorrectly returned by RegExp.prototype.exec and String.prototype.match as an empty string rather than undefined, making it impossible to determine group participation.
```

Use a simpler RegExp:

```
var pattern = ":.\\d+/.*";
var data = {"foo":":8080/site2/public_html", "bar":":80/site1/www"};

var elements = (RegExp(pattern).exec(data.foo) + "," + RegExp(pattern).exec(data.bar)).split(",");
```

Use a [replaceValue callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453409/1113772#20232651) as an alternative to capturing groups to workaround the browser bugs.

**References**

- [XRegExp: Browser fixes](http://xregexp.com/cross_browser/)